# unique constraint in grails for a subclass

Tags: grails

```
class A extends B{

    Control control

    static constraints = {
        control unique: true    
    }

    static mapping = {
        discriminator "L"
    }
}
```

In this code i have Control class relationship i want this control object to be unique

```
class B {
    float cost
    String activeStatus = 'Y'

    static constraints = {
        activeStatus inList:['Y','N']
    }

    static belongsTo = [ country:Country ]

    static mapping = {
        discriminator "S"
    }

    String toString() {
        "$cost"
    }
}
```

in my superclass i have cost as a property and in my country controller i'm creating object for A and adding to country

```
def control= Control.get( controlId )
def a = new A( control:control, cost:costId )
country.B(a)
country.save(flush:true)
```

what i want is when i'm providing values for control and cost, control must be uniquely saved in the database and each time cost should be updated... i.e, i want control must be unique

Comment: What is the problem you face?